# Getting a hotspot without root

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I've read several articles on how exactly to do this, but none of them seems to work. I can't root my G Flex 2 (because I have ZV9), so that route is inaccessible. FoxFi initializes but I get a warning that I need to subscribe to a hotspot service. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Why not take the native (built-in) hotspot feature – is it missing from your device?

Comment: Yes, but I receive a notification that I need to subscribe to the hotspot service.

Comment: Maybe your provider detects the "tethering" and wants some extra money. The built-in hotspot feature requires no subscription. Funny that USB tethering works; have you tried the built-in variant of that as well?

Comment: Didn't even know there was that option. New to android.

Comment: Thought so – hence I've mentioned it. An app is not always the only solution :) Guess I should make that an answer for you to accept? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded Pdanet+ and used the USB option, **not** the Wi-Fi one.

Comment: I think I may have flagged in haste. Is this an answer or you intended to reply to somebody?

Comment: Answer. Solved my issue